# How to transfer data between components?

Tags: angular, eventemitter

I need your help. I have 2 components: `header` and `sidena`. I use the `material-UI` library. In the sidenav component, I try to create an opened variable that is responsible for opening the `sidenav` and use `EventEmmiter` to pass it to the `header` component, but I get an error in `sidenav.component.html`:

`Type EventEmitter<boolean> is not assignable to type boolean`

I have 2 questions: how do I pass a variable in the header component to open sidenav and do I understand correctly that the `.emit` method provides a certain type to our `eventEmmiter`? Thank you very much

sidenav.component.ts

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidena',
  templateUrl: './sidena.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidena.component.css']
})

export class SidenaComponent implements OnInit {

@Output() opened = new EventEmitter<boolean>()

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.opened.emit(false);
 }
}
```

sidenav.component.html

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
   <mat-sidenav mode="side" [(opened)]="opened">
      Sidenav
   </mat-sidenav>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

header.component.ts

```
import {Component, HostListener, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-header',
   templateUrl: './header.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() opened

ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

header.component.html

```
<header>
   <button (click)="opened=!opened">Toggle Opened</button>
   <app-sidena></app-sidena>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are trying to use two-way data binding in your SidenaComponent in html:

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
   <mat-sidenav mode="side" [(opened)]="opened">
      Sidenav
   </mat-sidenav>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

but it should be

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
   <mat-sidenav mode="side" (opened)="open($event)">
      Sidenav
   </mat-sidenav>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

then in typescript of SidenaComponent you should correctly react to opened event like that:

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidena',
  templateUrl: './sidena.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidena.component.css']
})

export class SidenaComponent implements OnInit {

@Output() opened = new EventEmitter<boolean>()

open(event): void {
  this.opened.emit(event);
 }
}
```

this way you get correct value from opened event of Material component. Next step is sending this value up, to your parrent component: HeaderComponent. And you should do it like this:

```
<header>
   <button (click)="opened=!opened">Toggle Opened</button>
   <app-sidena (opened)="isOpened($event)"></app-sidena>
</header>
```

And in typescript:

```
import {Component, HostListener, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-header',
   templateUrl: './header.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
private opened: boolean;
isOpened(event): void {
   this.opened = event;
}
}
```

This way you have state of side menu in your header component.

Also if you need to pass value down to SidenaComponent from HeaderComponent just use @Input and pass it down.

Comment: Thank you. One question, what does `emit` method doing in simple words? Can you explain?

Comment: method `emit` is creating event in EventEmitter, then whoever is listening on EventEmitter will be called and value that you are passing in `emit` method will be sent to every listener. Thats why you are using `$event` in html file.

Comment: If you have more questions just ask in private messeges, also can you mark my answer as correct? Of corse if you think than i explained everything about the topic, and my answer was helpfull ^^

Comment: I have question: can i add you to some social media and ask you some questions about some topics???

Comment: You can add me on Twitter, if you go to my profile there should be an icon.

Answer (score 0):

An other way is to use a service in which you store variables. You can then access those variables in every other components.

To generate this service:

```
ng generate service yourService
```

For more infos, here's the official documentation:
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4